# How to get purchaseHistory for IAPs with BillingClient

Tags: android-billing

As the documentation says:

```
queryPurchaseHistoryAsync():

Returns the most recent purchase made by the user for each SKU, even if that purchase is expired, canceled, or consumed.
```

So lets say I would like to make an IAP for the user to **remove Ads forever from my app.**

How do I decide **with a fresh install if that user already purchased that IAP** if this function **also returns the "canceled" IAPS?**

I would like to query **the actually purchased IAPS, not everything.** Becuase that way a user could unlock the Ad free version with a cancelled IAP.

---

To make it worse, the `Purchase` class **doesn't have status like "cancelled" or "consumed"** I cannot decide the state of the user's purchased IAPS.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The billing client documentation states it checks for the user.

Then we have the question: **Who is the user**

If you look at the steps taken for the billing api on https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview then you see that a connection to google play is needed.

What happens then is that the current user on android, the account they are signed in with on google play and their mobile device is determined to be the user.

So if they purchased it via google play in app, it will always be assigned to that user on google play and that is what's being queried by this. No matter on which device they are logged in, Their tablet, smartwatch, phone, television, etc...

**How to get a list of actually bought products**

Instead of using async that gives you everything included abandoned shopping carts I suggest you use https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#querypurchases

That way Get purchases details for all the items actually bought and paid within your app. This method uses a cache of Google Play Store app without initiating a network request.

> Note: It's recommended for security purposes to go through purchases
>   verification on your backend (if you have one) by calling the
>   following API:
>   https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get

If you read that API link it's easy to check with the online cache if the purchase was valid with a simple GET request.

Personally I would build in a check if the phone is suspect to be rooted before doing the manual background check with the purchases API that sends a request to the store.

Phones that are not rooted have a higher trust level, as the user are probaly not very tech savvy and will not have a shimmer of a clue how to circumvent such checks, and the google play cache will be updated regularly, reflecting trustworthy data.

When a phone is suspect to be rooted(you can read protected directories/write to them), then perform the check online if they bought the stuff each time you deem it neccesary.

Comment: Thank you kind stranger